# Reverse of clip to bounds ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a UIView that contain another collectionview. the collectionview layout are out of the bounds of the super view. What i want to do is the opposite of clip to bounds and since my superview is partially transparent i don't want to see the collectionview below the view:

```
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   +                          +
   +       super View         +
   +                          +
   +                          +
-----------------------------------
-  +  collection view         +   -
-  +                          +   -
-----------------------------------
   +                          +
   +                          +
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

should be

```
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   +                          +
   +       super View         +
   +                          +
   +                          +
---+                          +---
-  +                          +  -
-  +                          +  -
---+                          +---
   +                          +
   +                          +
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

any idea??

Comment: you add collection view progrmatically or storyboard?

Comment: currently is from storyboard but i can change it if necessary.

Comment: Add mask(CAShapeLayer) to your collectionView's CALayer and update it at layoutSubviews (change it according to position in superview)